# AWS Lambda Unable to import module 'index': Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda

After doing some research it seems that this issues is usually caused by zipping the parent folder rather than the files themselves. I've zipped the files correctly both from the command line as well as manually, and I still get the same error.

I also tried sudo chmod -R 775 node_modules which had no effect.

Here's the error log:

```
Unable to import module 'index': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous>  (/var/task/classes/ancillaryInvoiceGenerator.js:3:24)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

The referenced line ancillaryInvoiceGenerator.js:3:24 is:

```
const NexService = require('../services/NexService');
```

Is this a pathing problem? But then why can't index.js be imported at all to begin with?

I'm banging my head against a wall and am open to any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: can you share more code of `InvoiceGenerator.js` and also the packaging structure of your zip file.

Comment: Its over 200 lines so I created a pastebin for it: https://pastebin.com/XUVMqxtF

Comment: Oh, and structure of zip is just index.js, node_modules, package.json and some folders for other classes

Comment: Also, what is the entry point of the function as seen by aws CLI or the lambda console ?